# What is the difference between kill and taskkill commands in Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

There is two commands in Windows Server, `kill` and `taskkill` that seems to have similar functionality. But I want to know their exact differences and their usages.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: There is no native 'kill' command in Windows.

Comment: But I can use such command in CMD. It looks like kill command in linux (its options are prefixed by dash). Where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Greg said, Windows doesn't have a native `kill` command, PowerShell has a alias `kill` for `Stop-Process`. If your cmd.exe responses to `kill` you have some external command somewhere in your path.